# How to Calculate the number of months between two dates in YYYYMM Format?

Tags: sql-server

For example I want to calculate the month difference from 190001

```
 Product  | YrMo   | Month_Num | 
 A        | 201602 | 1392      |
 A        | 201603 | 1393      |
 B        | 201605 | 1396      |
```

Can Datediff be manipulated or is there another method?

Comment: Note: if all you need is the difference in months between 1900-01 and any given YrMo, it's just `(LEFT(YrMo, 4) - 1900) * 12 + RIGHT(YrMo, 2) - 1`, which will give you the output of a `DATEDIFF` between 0 and any given YrMo... For a date other than 1900-01, `DATEDIFF` becomes easier.

Answer (score 2):

--If they are integers, this is most likely the fastest (fewest conversions)

--INTEGER division by 100 gets you the year.

--MOD division by 100 gets you the month.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE INT = 190001;
DECLARE @ENDDATE INT = 201602;

select (@ENDDATE/100 - @STARTDATE/100) * 12 
           + (@ENDDATE % 100 - @STARTDATE % 100);
```

**OR**

```
SELECT (YrMo/ 100 - 190001 / 100) * 12 + (YrMo % 100 - 190001 % 100)
```

Comment: Thanks M. Ali!  That was my first ever post to Stack Overflow.  Looks like I need to learn how to format answers better.  :)

Comment: Yes the columns are Integers. This is lean and tidy. I really like it and will start using this method going forward. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Product
    ,YrMo
    ,DATEDIFF(month,'1/1/1900',DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(YrMo,4),RIGHT(YrMo,2),1)) AS Month_Num
FROm
    TableName
```

Seeing you know it is always 6 digits just split up the string and build a date from part `year`, `month`, and then `1` for `day` and use `DATEDIFF` from there.